# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen, Working code as below in body

Tags: ruby, string

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'roo'
require 'pathname'

Dir.glob("**/*.xlsx") do |file|
 xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
 bookname             = xlsx.column(1)
 chapter_number_array = xlsx.column(2).uniq

 chapter_number_array.each do |chapter|
   book_name      = bookname[1] if bookname
   chapter_number = chapter if (chapter_number_array && (chapter != "Chapter"))
   Dir.mkdir(book_name) unless File.exists?(book_name)
   Dir.mkdir("#{book_name}/#{chapter_number}") unless File.exists?("#{book_name}/#{chapter_number}")
   xlsx.column(3).each do |md|
      book_chapter_path = Pathname.new("#{book_name}/#{chapter_number}")
      output_name = "#{book_chapter_path}/#{File.basename(md.partition('-').first, '.*')}.md" if (md != "Verse")
      output = File.open("#{output_name}", 'w')
      output << "hello"
    end
  end
end
```

## [.xlsx file_link_which_i_am_parsing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_-sckPdT2dlak9fbFZYVC1SVGs/view?usp=sharing)

> From link's file first column is directory 1, second column is 2 as child directory, third is again child directory and i am creating file of fourth column's first character(data is 1-3 then i am creating file as 1.md) in last child folder. I am putting file with any name folder where is my script available.

### Output of "output_name" variable as below:

- 1 John/1/1.md
- 1 John/1/3.md
- 1 John/1/5.md
- .............
- 1 John/5/16.md
- 1 John/5/18.md
- 1 John/5/20.md

## Getting error with "output" variable as below:

> > `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -  (Errno::ENOENT)
>
> I have searched on google but still not understading.

## error as below:

> ./notes_to_markdown.rb:21:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -  (Errno::ENOENT)
>       from ./notes_to_markdown.rb:21:in`open'
>       from ./notes_to_markdown.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
>       from ./notes_to_markdown.rb:18:in`each'
>       from ./notes_to_markdown.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
>       from ./notes_to_markdown.rb:11:in`each'
>       from ./notes_to_markdown.rb:11:in `block in <main>'
>       from ./notes_to_markdown.rb:5:in`glob'
>       from ./notes_to_markdown.rb:5:in `'

## [git_repository_for_script_file](https://github.com/Bridgeconn/TN_TO_MD.git)

Comment: Posting the full error stack trace would help

Comment: What code string causes this error?

Comment: I have already put all error with explanation, please point out line of code so that i can explan more.

Comment: If you run that script with give file, easily you can see error. @SergiiK

Comment: What does the `"1 "` prefix in `output_name` mean? Is that a part of the file name? Does the folder exist?

Comment: No error on my system. Is that code snippet from `notes_to_markdown.rb` file?

Comment: "1 " is file name @spi

Comment: "1 " is file name @spickermann

Comment: @SergiiK above code exactly from notes_to_markdown.rb frile

Comment: I have added git repositiry now in above question for script

Comment: It looks like lines ordering is not persisted in your snippet. 21st line is `end`.

Comment: @SergiiK I need solution not your alingment. If you do not want to solve issue, please dont make unnecessary for reputation ;)

Comment: One question. Tell me how can you debug someone elses code if you do not know what part raises error? I don't  mention what OS/ruby versions are used etc. Your question sounds like: "This code doesn't work, fix it for me and do not ask me anything..."

Comment: @SergiiK it is basic string manipulation and it will run with any version. Allignment is proper in code. By the way i have resolved issue as below answer. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to test if #{book_name} directory exist before you create your file

Comment: Did you check on your system? Please without checking code do not answer. I am still facing same issue  @IDIR GACI

Answer (score 0):

## I have resolved my question. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'roo'

Dir.glob("**/*.xlsx") do |file|
  xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
  bookname = xlsx.column(1)

  cahpter_number_array = xlsx.column(2).uniq

  cahpter_number_array.each do |chapter|
    if (chapter != "Chapter")
      book_name      = bookname[1] if bookname
      chapter_number = chapter if (chapter != "Chapter")

      Dir.mkdir(book_name) unless File.exists?(book_name)
      Dir.mkdir("#{book_name}/#{chapter_number}") unless File.exists?("#{book_name}/#{chapter_number}")

      xlsx.column(3).each do |md|
        if (md != "Verse")
          output_name = "#{book_name}/#{chapter_number}/#{File.basename(md.partition('-').first, '.*')}.md" 
          output = File.open("#{output_name}", 'w')
          output << "hello"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```